# Diff for Powerpoint

Tags: diff, powerpoint

In Word, there is an option to compare two documents and find out the differences between the two documents. I'm looking for a similar function to compare two Powerpoint documents. Ideally, it would list the individual slides that are different, the differences in each slide between the versions and when the changes were made. However, I can't find a menu option for this functionality (I'm using Office 2007). Am I missing something?

If this functionality is not in Powerpoint, are there 3rd party tools doing this?

Comment: What programming language are you doing this in?

Comment: I'll probably end up using some form of VB , but for now I'd just like to see how "good" the diff information will be. Worrying about using the information will be the next step.

Comment: As far as I know there isn't a built in diff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there was some functionality in PowerPoint 2003 to compare two PowerPoint files, but as I don't have access to a working installation, I can't really tell about the functionality of the compare. As Ben has noted, you can find a number of 3rd party tools doing a diff.

This feature has been discontinued in Office 2007. As far as I can tell from the documentation, there is some integration with SharePoint that should be used, but the whole concept is very differnt from a presentation diff. The way I understand it, you can version individual slides (with get and commit type of functionality), create new presentations from existing slides and be notified when a slide you are using is changed by another user and committed to the repository.

Answer (score 29):

Upgrade to Powerpoint 2010 or 2013 and choose Compare in the Review tab.  See this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYd-B_3V2oo

Answer (score 3):

Failing all else, if you have Office 2007 you can always save the ppt as an OOXML document.

Comment: and if you have Office 2010, you can save it in ODP format - much nicer.

Answer (score 2):

Using tortoisegit scripts to diff office docs
http://xcafebabe.blogspot.mx/2012/09/sexy-comparison-of-word-documents-with.html

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but this thread is the first hit on Google for me, so maybe someone can find my solution useful.

I'm using Microsoft Office 2010 and I find the Compare feature a bit confusing. All I want is to compare two different PPTX documents word by word, I just don't need to check document properties.

So for me it has been enough to save both PPTX documents as pdf and then use the [DiffPDF Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/diffpdf_portable) tool to see the differences between the two.

Hope this will be useful :-)

Comment: That's really useful. I saved both files as RTF outlines, then used Word's diff features that are already built-in

Comment: sadly there is no mac version for DiffPDF.